# Allowing touch scroll for devices that don't issue proper touch gestures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a "touchscreen" panel which I am displaying a website on.  On a normal touchscreen it is fine.  However this particular panel doesn't seem to recognise touch gestures properly, and so you're basically just pushing a mouse around with your finger.  This has the irritating consequence that the website cannot be scrolled with your finger - only using the scrollbar.  The hardware/driver isn't fixable, so I need to resolve this another way.

Are there any jquery/javascript methods I could use to allow touch scrolling on this kind of screen, where it's essentially only a mouse?

(I can't really provide a jsfiddle, as it relies on having a touchscreen that's not a proper touchscreen!)

Comment: If the screen has a special API that you can use (e.g. [TUIO](http://www.tuio.org)) you could fetch this on a server and update the page with a web socket. That means however that the user will have to launch a piece of software *outside* the browser before opening the page.

Comment: If you cannot do this, you may use the mouse move events instead an map them to scroll. However it will mean that any mouse event will be treated as such, i.e. the page won't be usable with a mouse anymore. Thus, you may want to make sure that you can disable this feature when needed.